# Entity Framework: Dynamically generate multiple OR condition on JOIN

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have problems designing LINQ query for EntityFramework that combines multiple conditions on attached entities with OR condition.

My classes (simplified):

```
public class EventMessage : EntityBase
{
    public IList<EventParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class EventParameter : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The goal is to obtain `EventMessages` which have at least one `EventParameter` which `Value` and `Name` equals one of the passed arguments (passed to query below by `QueryParameters` of type `IList<EventParameter>`). The problems is that I want my query to be dynamic, ie. it would be able to generate condition independently on `QueryParameters.Count()`

I have tried following approaches:

```
//Throws NotSupportedException when generating SQL
//Message: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'EventParameter'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."
DataContext.Queryable<EventMessage>()
    .Where(em => QueryParameters.Any(qp => em.Parameters.Any(p => p.Name == qp.Name && p.Value == qp.Value)));

//Throws NotSupportedException when generating SQL 
//Message: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'FilterByParameters'"
DataContext.Queryable<EventMessage>().Where(em => FilterByParameters(em, QueryParameters));

public bool FilterByParameters(EventMessage eventMessage, IList<EventParameter> queryParameters)
{
    bool result = false;
    foreach (EventParameter queryParam in queryParameters)
    {
        result |= eventMessage.Parameters.Any(x => x.Name == queryParam.Name && x.Value == queryParam.Value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Of course, it would be no problem to design query for given number of `QueryParameters` - I could join OR-conditions within and expression inside `.Where()`, however I would like to have a query that work independently on paramemeters' count. Is it possible? Using EF 6.1.3.

Comment: you need to build an expression tree and pass that as the parameter to your filter.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, will look into this, might be more efficient than using `Union` as suggested below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Union.

```
DataContext.Queryable<EventMessage>().Where(p => p.Bla == blub).Where(p => something else)
```

will be an AND. For or you should be able to do something like

```
DataContext.Queryable<EventMessage>().Where(p => p.Bla == blub).Union(p => something else)
```

EDIT:
If it is not clear right away: You can combine these filters like this:

```
IQueryable<...> ApplyOrFilter(IQueryable<...> query, ...)
{
   return query.Union(...);
}
```